# Is there a minimal php5ts.dll?

Tags: php, dll

I've completed my web app and am using mongoose to serve the php pages. The whole app & mongoose is less then 2MB.

The php5ts.dll is almost 5MB so that really adds bloat. Also, my app is very minimal so I don't need many of the php features, ie. mysql & crypto.

I've used UPX to compress it down to 1.7MB, however thats the same I was getting before using 7zip so its not a big deal.  I've read on [winbider forums](http://winbinder.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=204) that some people recompiled it and made it even smaller.  Would anyone know where I could find these minimal php5ts.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can recompile. Use './configure' keys (or how is it in windows, maybe, Makefile?) to add/remove functionality you need, consult the manual for the exact module directives for sets of functions.

You may Google for a pre-compiled library, but it's always better to recompile it so it meets your needs, shrinks in size and overall - fits better ;)

Also consider using packers like [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/):

```
php5ts.dll: 1290 kB (62% compression)
```

(found here: [Compiling PHP with no extra weight](http://winbinder.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=204) via Googling for "UPX php5ts.dll" )

P.S. If you had read answers on ServerFault, you would have known this ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your own version. The source is publicly available, and this way you can include exactly the features you want.

Read about compiling on windows [here](http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows).

Comment: I've never had good luck compliling anything from source, so I was trying to avoid that.